Hairy ball theorem Devil and Angel game
Devil is trying to convince Angel that the hairy ball theorem is false by presenting a "counterexample". The theorem is true, so Devil is cheating. As Angel is examining the ball from the outside while flying around it on a continuous path that he is free to choose, Devil is busy re-combing the other side of the ball to keep singularities hidden from Angel.
Angel will call foul whenever he sees a singularity, or whenever he sees Devil's work, i.e. the field changing. However Angel doesn't remember what he saw previously; he can only observe the momentary state of the field and detect its changes happening on the part of the ball's surface that he can momentarily see from his POV.
Angel wins if he catches Devil cheating. Devil wins if he has a strategy to never get caught cheating. Who wins?
Depending on $r$, who wins if Angel is confined to a larger ball of radius $r$ concentric with the hairy ball (i.e. can only see strictly less than half of the ball's surface)?
In those cases when Devil can win, what is his strategy?

What exactly is the Angel's range of vision? Can he see the entire (closed) hemisphere that he is on?

There are two versions, Angel at infinity (hemisphere), and Angel at distance $r$ from the center of the ball (cap). But on second thought, for the game as stated, I suspect Devil always wins. Nothing prevents him from just moving the singularities around and leaving increasingly messy but nonetheless singularity-free field. Perhaps if Angel could require Devil to declare some kind of measure of the maximum local "messiness" that his "solution" nowhere exceeds, then Angel might win because Devil would eventually be forced to make more mess than that.
